# Chrome freezing with alert

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I have this code snippet in the script tag after the `body` tag:

```
window.setTimeout("myFunc()",100);


function myFunc()
{
    if("<%=variable%>" == "")
    {
        alert("sample alert!");
    }
}
```

There is a strange bug that it is happening. Sometimes, when the user clicks "ok" in the alert, Chrome stops responding, and the only way to restart it is by closing the process in the task manager. This only happens with Chrome, tried with Firefox and Internet Explorer and it works fine. This happens multiple times, not only in the page that contains this snippet, and it always involves an alert being clicked.

Any clues on why this is happening?

Comment: @epascarello He's using `Timeout`, not `Interval`.

Comment: Don't call `setTimeout()` with a string containing a function call. Instead, just pass a reference to the function (no quotes) as in: `window.setTimeout(myFunc,100);`

Comment: The script is *after* the `body` tag?  Do you mean as a child of `body`, or as a sibling?

Comment: Try putting your function call inside document.ready({window.setTimeout..

Comment: @bestinamir No one has mentioned the use of JQuery at all.

Comment: @Amy The `body` *tag* = `<body>`. The `body` *element* is `<body></body>`, so after the `body` tag would imply as a child within it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm aware and agree with that, but I think the OP should be the one to clarify what he meant.

Comment: I mean that it is after the body CLOSING tag, sorry about that.

Comment: @DiogoSantos Thank you for clarifying.  Script tags are not valid as direct children of the `html` element; the only valid children of the `html` element are `head` and `body`.  Script tags *must* go inside `head` or `body`.

Comment: While it won't really affect what's going on with your page, you should know that nothing is allowed after `</body>` except `</html>`. Place your `<script>` **inside** the `<head>` or `<body>` sections. This will make your code valid, but it won't change the way it's executing.

Comment: Also problem with Chrome could be unrelated to this, for example due to some addon which needs disabling.. Try replicating it on other computers.. if it is just reset or reinstall your Chrome..

Comment: It happens on multiple users in multiple machines